# Issue in title of frame during allowframebreaks

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, allowframebreaks

Question:

When I use allowframebreaks in bibliography, the title of the slide is changed on the next page (on the first slide Reference I and on the second slide Reference II). How did this happen?

What I have so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usepackage[f]{esvect}

\usecolortheme{beaver}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
\usepackage{setspace}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]{\textbf{References}}
    \begin{thebibliography}{10}
        \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
    \bibitem{oberbeck1879warmeleitung}
    \alert{{\"U}ber die W{\"a}rmeleitung der Fl{\"u}ssigkeiten bei Ber{\"u}cksichtigung der Str{\"o}mungen infolge von Temperaturdifferenzen}
    \newblock {Oberbeck, Anton}
    \newblock {Wiley Online Library 1879}.

    \bibitem{oberbeck1888uber}
    \alert{Uber die Bewegungsercheinungen der Atmosphere. Sitz. Ber. K}
    \newblock {Oberbeck, A}
    \newblock {Preuss. Akad. Miss 1888}.

    \bibitem{boussinesq1897theorie}
    \alert{Boussinesq, Joseph}
    \newblock  {Th{\'e}orie de l'{\'e}coulement tourbillonnant et tumultueux des liquides dans les lits rectilignes a grande section}
    \newblock {Gauthier-Villars 1897}.

    \bibitem{bachelier1900theorie}
    \alert{Bachelier, Louis}
    \newblock {Annales scientifiques de l'{\'E}cole normale sup{\'e}rieure}
    \newblock {1900}.

    \bibitem{struve1931astrophysik}
    \alert{Struve, Otto}
    \newblock {The Astrophysical Journal}
    \newblock {1931}.

        \end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `allowframebreaks` the following is in the `beamer` class [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf):

> [...] If there is a frame title, each of the pages will have this
>   frame title, with a special note added indicating which page of the
>   frame that page is. By default, this special note is a Roman number.
>   However, this can be changed [...].